# Testcases skipped:Issue on applying Pytest-dependency and Pytest-Ordering

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-dependency, pytest-order

Tried intergrating pytest-dependency and pytest-ordering in my testcases that are in different python files and issue below rises where dependent testcases are skipped. Seen similar issues here in stackoverflow but this could be a unique one.

## test_mod_01.py

```
import pytest
from pages.Page1 import LaunchPage

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestPage1:
    @pytest.mark.dependency()
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_page1(self):
        pass
        self.lp = LaunchPage(self.driver)
        self.lp.clickButton1()
```

## test_mod_02.py

```
import pytest
import softest
from flaky import flaky
from pages.Page2 import TalentPage
from pages.Page3 import CVPage


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestPage2_3(softest.TestCase):

    @flaky(max_runs=3, min_passes=2)
    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["testcases/test_mod_01.py::TestPage1::test_page1"], scope="session")
    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_page2(self):
        self.tp = TalentPage(self.driver)
        self.tp.scroll_down()
        self.tp.clickButton2()
        self.tp.clickButton3()

    @flaky(max_runs=3, min_passes=2)
    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["TestPage2_3::test_BuildCV_page_2"], scope="session")
    @pytest.mark.run(order=3)
    def test_page3(self):
        self.cvp = CVPage(self.driver)
        self.cvp.clickButton4()
        self.cvp.clickButton5()
        self.cvp.clickButton6()
        self.cvp.clickButton7()
```

## Conftest

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


@pytest.fixture()
def setup(request, browser):
    if browser == "chrome":
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    elif browser == "firefox":
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    elif browser == "edge":
        options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get("https://example.com/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield request.cls.driver
    request.cls.driver.quit()


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

## Error

```
(venv) xxxx % pytest -v -s --browser chrome testcases
=============================================================== test session starts ===============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.11.4, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0 -- xxxx
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: xxxx
plugins: flaky-3.7.0, dependency-0.5.1, ordering-0.6
collected 3 items

testcases/test_mod_01.py::TestPage1::test_page1 PASSED
testcases/test_mod_02.py::TestPage2_3::test_page2 SKIPPED (test_page2 depends on testcases/test_...)
testcases/test_mod_02.py::TestPage2_3::test_page3 SKIPPED (test_page3 depends on TestP...)

========================================================== 1 passed, 2 skipped in 14.66s ==========================================================
```

Even when i combine the test_mod_01 with test_mod_02 in one class, the independent testcase runs and other two are skipped. Tried to initialize the test_mod_01 class in test_mod_02 and run, but still wont work.

Comment: Use the successor `pytest-order` instead of `pytest-ordering` with the option [--order-dependencies](https://pytest-order.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#order-dependencies), it will automatically order the tests according to the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @MrBeanBremen. So should I add the --order-dependencies option to the conftest.py file? I tried running this command pytest -v -s --browser --order-dependencies chrome testcases but ended up with "unrecognized arguments --order-dependencies". Do you perhaps have an example of how to apply the --order-dependencies in my context. Thank you.

Comment: Adding it to the command line is correct. If it didn't get recognized, you probably don't have installed `pytest-order`. You could also [add it to pytest.ini](https://pytest-order.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thanks for the feedback. Its true i didnot install pytest-order. I have installed it and created a folder at root directory pytest.ini, then added the code provided in the document and tried to run test cases with this command pytest -v -s --browser --order-dependencies chrome testcases, ended up with the error "argparse.ArgumentError: argument --order-dependencies: conflicting option string: --order-dependencies"Without adding the pytest.ini, the other 2 test cases are skipped
[pytest]; always order tests with dependency markers
addopts = --order-dependencies. Kindly advise.

Comment: Ok, putting the option both in the command line and in the pytest.ini obviously leads to that message. I just tried to reproduce your setup as far as possible, and it works fine for me. If you can't get it to work, you may write a question in `pytest-order` (if possible, with a minimal reproducible example). The comments here are not really suited for this.